# Is it possible to create a dust file that only displays at most n elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

As the title is suggesting, I would like to know if it is possible to create a dust file that only displays a certain number of elements from an array. Say at most 20, if the array has more than 20 elements.

I can handle the situation using plain JavaScript, but it would be nice if Dust.js could also handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $idx value

```
{#items}
  {@lt key=$idx value=20}{! output the item info !}{/lt}
{/items}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work... does that work only for displaying exactly 20 or at most 20? I have 10 or more lines of code between `{!` and `!}`...I mean I have some divs, spans, etc, between my `{#items}` and `{/items}`

Comment: His code should work. It does require you to include `dust-helpers` if you don't already have it.